# Is there any way to monitor internal azure data factory pipeline like Payload size, number of retries, Concurrent Jobs and similar parameters?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-monitoring, azure-data-factory

I want to monitor the Azure data factory pipeline parameters like number of pipeline retries, payload size, Concurrent jobs running, and similar compute infrastructure and other performance parameters. These are the parameters that might affect the performance of the data service. Is there any way to monitor these? I have already checked the service-specific metrics parameters available in diagnostic settings.

Comment: I think this document can help you in monitoring  your azure data factory pipelines by using azure portal and powershell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-monitor-manage-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

At this time it is not possible to get the internal details you are looking for but seems like a great feedback. I would recommend you to please log your feedback in feedback forum here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community

All the feedback shared in this forum are actively monitored and reviewed by ADF Product team.